# When I res.redirect(`/relative/url`), the response received is PATCH 404 Not found. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Problem: I want to 'update' a document saved on mongoDB, so i used `Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, { 'status': req.body.status })`. Till here, every thing is working fine. BUT, as soon as i add `res.redirect('/user/control_articles')` below it to redirect the user to another page, it returns 404 in browser console.

How can i properly **"update"** *then* **"redirect"** the user?

```
//main.js
// pre_id comes from another variable, its ok

pub_btn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    fetch(`/user/new_article`, {
      method: `PATCH`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'event': 'publish',
        'status': 'publish',
        'id': pre_id
      })
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
```

```
//router.js

router.patch(`/new_article`, userController.article_update)
```

```
//controller.js

exports.article_update = (req, res) => {
  if(req.body.event === 'publish'){
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, { 'status': req.body.status })
    res.redirect(`/user/control_articles`)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the api endpoint in your backend server which you're trying to redirect? 404 response code means that url doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to define the GET endpoint which serves /user/control_articles

You should define it like the patch endpoint

```
//router.js

router.get(`/user/control_articles`, userController.articles_get)
router.patch(`/new_article`, userController.article_update)
```

If you doesn't forget then try awaiting until the promise is resolved using async/await syntax

```
//controller.js

exports.article_update = async (req, res) => {
  if(req.body.event === 'publish'){
    await Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, { 'status': req.body.status })
    res.redirect(`/user/control_articles`)
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have the GET endpoint. `exports.article = (req, res) => {  Blog.find({}, { "id": "", "title": ", "status": "" }, (err, blogs) => { if (!err) { res.render(`control_articles`, { blogs }) } })}`